# adding a child node to specific node in c#

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

I have a problem adding a childnode to specific node. Here is my code:
Method for painting tree

```
public void paint()
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode("Katalogas");  
        root.Name = "root";  
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);



        foreach (string or in categories)
        {
            TreeNode subcat = new TreeNode(or);
            subcat.Name = or;
            root.Nodes.Add(subcat);
        }

        foreach (Preke or in PrekiuListas)
        {
            TreeNode subcat = new TreeNode(or.name);
            subcat.Name = or.name;
            TreeNode temp = FindNode(or.category);
            temp.Nodes.Add(subcat);
        }
```

Method for finding node

```
private TreeNode FindNode(String name)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes)
        {
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                return FindNode(name);
            if (node.Name == name)
                return node;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I can add one child node to both nodes, but when i try to add another, i get stack overflow exception.. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the root node along with the method:

```
private TreeNode FindNode(String name, TreeNode root)
{
    if(root.Name == name) return root;
    Stack<TreeNode> nodes = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    nodes.Push(root);
    while(nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        var node = nodes.Pop();
        foreach(TreeNode n in node.Nodes){
           if (n.Name == name) return n;
           nodes.Push(n);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
//Usage
var node = FindNode(someName, treeView1.Nodes[0]);
//if your treeView has more root nodes, you have to loop through them
TreeNode node = null;
foreach(TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes){
  node = FindNode(someName, node);
  if(node != null) break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Edited my code like this, still the same stack overflow exception.. Any other solution?

Comment: @user3061057 I'm not sure how exactly you tried it, looks like you have very very many nodes? so using **recursive method** won't work because of the limit in call stack size. Try using the updated code, **however**, I think you should consider the answer of ***Prahlad Yeri*** with the use of `TreeNodeCollection.Find` method, it's very convenient indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just that of finding the node name, you can use the built-in TreeNodeCollection.Find() method for better performance:

```
public TreeNode[] Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren);
```

Example:

```
n.Nodes.Find("name", true);
```

The second parameter indicates that you want to search in all nodes recursively.

Also, this returns an entire TreeNode[] array, not a single node. So, you have to loop in them to fill or take the node[0] element if yo want to use just the first one.